# How can I set a nested property value in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

I want to set an element.style.height property from clojurescript, but this code unfortunately fails:

```
(set! (-> (sel1 tr :.ragslide) .-style .-height) (content-height))
```

(sel1 selects a DOM element, it's a macro from the Dommy library)

With the following error:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: 
Assert failed: Can't set! local var or non-mutable field
(or (nil? local) (and (:field local) (or (:mutable local) (:unsynchronized-mutable local) (:volatile-mutable local)))) at line 79  {:tag :cljs/analysis-error, :file nil, :line 79, :column 7}
```

How can I set that property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, wow, this seems to be really weird. It failed to work because that code was inside a core.async block which messed everything up...

Comment: This has been since fixed in core.async master

Answer (score 0):

I think `(-> (sel1 tr :.ragslide) .-style .-height)` you got is a value of height, you can not set it with a new value.

If you want to add a height element in style, try
`set-style!` function.